# Search function when one field is blank

Tags: php, mysql

I need to know if there's a more efficient way to do a search when a user leaves a blank field

```
<select name="department">
    <option value="">Select Department</option>
    <option value="value1">Value1</option>
    <option value="value2">Value2</option>
</select>
<select name="course">
    <option value="">Select Course</option>
    <option value="value1">Value1</option>
    <option value="value2">Value2</option>
</select>
```

My question is how do I do this?
My own conclusion was to use a variety of

```
if(isset($_GET['dept']) && !isset)
```

and so on then corresponding each with its own `SELECT * FROM....` but this seems so bothersome and not that dynamic especially if I decided to add a third or fourth field and it'll be a whole new additional set of ifs.
Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Perhaps in MySQL?

Comment: Well, I don't know if what I'll say is more efficient but I wouldn't do the conditions for the entire SQL string, instead I'd set the partial strings of each evaluated element and concatenate it all to get a full final string at the end of the conditional statement. Then add that to the SQL query. Also, that would be a lot easier to read and to edit for additional fields. But object-oriented style would do a lot better too.

Comment: Could you give me links for tutorials on what your saying if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: I could write it on my own... I actually think I've done something similar too. I don't really know where to find it, but I'll search and if anything pops up, I will link them down below in another comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I said in the comments section, I don't know if this is more efficient, but I think it's easier to read and will help ease the pain of changing all conditions of your statement. I did not find tutorials about things like that, but here's a modified example of something I've done in the past for a real estate company:

```
if(isset($_POST['search'])){
    $prov_query = '';
    $city_query = '';
    $build_query = '';
    $trans_query = '';
    $amb_query = '';
    $prov = $_POST['province'];
    $city = $_POST['city'];
    $build = $_POST['building'];
    $trans = $_POST['transaction'];
    $amb = $_POST['amb'];
    if($prov != ''){
        $prov_query = "`province`='$prov'";
    }
    if($city != ''){
        $city_query = "`city`='$city'";
    }
    if($build != '' && $build != '0'){
        $build_query = "AND `building`='$build'";
    }
    if($trans != '' && $trans != '0'){
        $trans_query = "AND `transaction`='$trans'";
    }
    if($amb != ''){
        if($amb == 5){
            $amb_query = "`amb`>='5'";
        } else {
            $amb_query = "`amb`='$amb'";
        }
    }
    $full_search_query = "SELECT * FROM `properties` WHERE $prov_query AND $city_query $build_query $trans_query AND $amb_query ORDER BY `id` DESC";
}
```

Please note, for search engines, you might want to use

```
"`column` LIKE '%$value%'"
```

or something similar as your SQL query, but my example required exact matches.

This has a few requirement tweaks, your conditionals will definitely be different than these, but I just want to share the idea. You see, all you have to do if you want to add more options (columns) is add a set of `if`'s that match your requirement and then accordingly add the variable to the final string. Hope this helps at least a little.